# Audio is playing twice in Android Media Player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my application I'm having a method responsible for playing file placed under raw directory. But when Ever I call that function in my `onResume()` method, sound is played twice. Even I have googled and tried different solutions. even by checking `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()` and then stopping the `MediaPlayer` instance but still didn't get any help.

```
private void EnglishSound(){
        if(mediaPlayer1!=null){
            if(mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer1.stop();

            }
            mediaPlayer1.reset();
             mediaPlayer1.release();
        }

        mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.p012);

            mediaPlayer1.start();

    }

 public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       EnglishSound();

    }
```

and `EnglishSound()` is called no where else in the whole activity. Even have tried debugging but it never enters the if block containing `isPlaying()`.

Comment: Try calling mediaPlayer1.release() if it is not null.

Answer (score 3):

Try to release onPause()

```
 public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mediaPlayer1 != null)
      mediaPlayer1.release();
}
```

Comment: thanks but it partially worked. as the sound contains wording "Do you want to start" but as applied your method it call "do do you want to start"  still it calls the sounds twice.